# Segre embedding and Hilbert polynomial of coherent sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, hilbert-function

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ and $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^m$ be smooth, projective subvarieties, $F$ and $G$ coherent, torsion-free, sheaves on $X$ and $Y$ with Hilbert polynomials $P_{F}$ and $P_G$, respectively (under the fixed embedding). Consider now the Segre embedding $X \times Y \subset \mathbb{P}^N$. Is the Hilbert polynomial of $\mbox{pr}_1^*F \otimes \mbox{pr}_2^*G$ under the Segre embedding just $P_F.P_G$?

Any idea/reference will be most welcome.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Using the Leray spectral sequence for either projection, for instance, you can prove the "Euler characteristic Kuenneth formula" that the Euler characteristic (for sheaf cohomology $k$-vector spaces) of $\text{pr}_X^*E_X\otimes \text{pr}_Y^*E_Y$ on $X\times Y$ equals the product of the Euler characteristics for $E_X$ on $X$ and for $E_Y$ on $Y$.  Now let $E_X$ equals $F(d)$ and let $E_Y$ equal $G(d)$ to conclude that the Hilbert polynomial of $\text{pr}_X^*F\otimes \text{pr}_Y^*G$ at the integer $d$ equals $P_F(d)\cdot P_G(d)$.